# Python Handle Errors while trying 2 variables

Tags: python

I'm trying to automate the gathering of mobility data from apple website with python script. One big obstacle I encountered was there are 2 variables I have to try the errors each time I run the script. The csv url structure is as following:

[https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com/covid19-mobility-data/2208HotfixDev**22**/v3/en-us/applemobilitytrends-**2022-03-03**'.csv](https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com/covid19-mobility-data/2208HotfixDev**22**/v3/en-us/applemobilitytrends-**2022-03-03**%27.csv)

The 2 variables I marked bold - *HotfixDev##* and *date*. As far as I know, there's no way to know either without trying (they don't seem to update this everyday or so).

I used the following code to handle errors for trying date variable:

```
def get_url(estimated):
    aapl_dl_date = estimated - dt.timedelta(days=1)
    url2 = aapl_dl_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    full_url = url1+url2+url3
    
    return full_url

while True:
    try:
        url = get_url(estimated)
        df = pd.read_csv(url)
        print('using link: ',url)
        break
    except HTTPError:
        estimated = estimated - dt.timedelta(days=1)
```

(estimated is a variable containing today's date as string)
This worked fine. Now I realized that HotfixDev ## is also a variable. Initially, my thought is for each date, do some sort of loop to go through 00, 01... 99, then if no luck goes to one day before. But because it involes error handling, I don't know how to stack it.

Any thought?

Comment: Do you have an example of a working link? Also, is there an index page somewhere listing the different data pages?

Comment: As of today, this is working:
https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com/covid19-mobility-data/2208HotfixDev22/v3/en-us/applemobilitytrends-2022-03-02.csv
and I don't think there is an index page...

Comment: I guess you could just loop through 00 to 99 and try to see which one returns a result. But I think I am missing something here. These files must be made available on the internet for some kind of reason. How did you know that these CSV files existed in the first place?

Comment: The csv is publicly available on https://covid19.apple.com/mobility, but the url of that file is dynamic as I described above. If loop works, it would be easy, but there is error handling involved. Unlike regular loop with a counter or a value to compare, if the url instance I try is not correct, HTTPError is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is an index file that lists the location of the CSV data file at https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com/covid19-mobility-data/current/v3/index.json. You can use this to access the CSV file programmatically, without having to loop through potential filenames.

I found this index file with the following process:

1. Visit https://covid19.apple.com/mobility
2. Press F12 to open the developer tools
3. Go to the network tab in the developer tools
4. Refresh the page

After doing that, all of the resources loaded by the page are listed in the network tab. That index.json file is one of them.

You can use this index file to load the CSV, like this:

```
import requests

BASE_URL = "https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com"

def fetch_index_data():
    url = BASE_URL + "/covid19-mobility-data/current/v3/index.json"
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()

def fetch_csv_text(base_path, csv_path):
    url = BASE_URL + base_path + csv_path
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.text

def main():
    index_data = fetch_index_data()
    csv_text = fetch_csv_text(
        index_data["basePath"],
        index_data["regions"]["en-us"]["csvPath"]
    )
    print(csv_text[:200])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also, it appears the same data is also available as JSON, currently at https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com/covid19-mobility-data/2209HotfixDev8/v3/en-us/applemobilitytrends.json. This will probably be easier to work with. You can fetch it by adapting the above code slightly.

```
import requests

BASE_URL = "https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com"

def fetch_index_data():
    url = BASE_URL + "/covid19-mobility-data/current/v3/index.json"
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()

def fetch_mobility_data(base_path, json_path):
    url = BASE_URL + base_path + json_path
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()

def main():
    index_data = fetch_index_data()
    mobility_data = fetch_mobility_data(
        index_data["basePath"],
        index_data["regions"]["en-us"]["jsonPath"]
    )
    print(list(mobility_data.keys()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```